# How did Gandalf survive the fall in the cavern in "Lord of the Rings - The Fellowship of the Ring" and reincarnated as "Gandalf the White"?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, the-lord-of-the-rings

In the "Lord of the Rings - The Fellowship of the Ring", while Gandalf the Grey was fighting inflaming demon Balrog, he fell into cavern. So, did he survived the fall or died and reincarnated as "Gandalf the White"? If survived then how does he become "Gandalf the White"?